# gdal_polygonize unable to open PNG

Tags: gdal, png

I use OSGeo4W on Windows 7 (64 bit) and included libpng16.dll
When I try

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>gdal_polygonize star.png bla
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 4: `star.png' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
Unable to open star.png
```

I copied star.png into C:\OSGeo4W64\bin (this is where gdal_polygonize batch file, python file and compiled python file are located )

What is the mistake?

UPDATE: I found out that I get the same mistake with a TIFF file but it works on JPEGs. Maybe the library/module for PNGs can't be found?

Comment: I can't see any mistake and your command works for me.

Comment: Try again with the full path name before star.png.

Comment: same :( I tried C:\OSGeo4W64\lib>gdal_polygonize C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\star.png bla

Comment: could it be caused by a wrong or missing environment variable ? I read that you usually add GDAL_DATA variable but I don't habe a gdal/data in my OSGeo4W64 directory..

Comment: If you are working inside the OSGeo4W Shell, the environment is set correctly. This would apply to all GDAL routines.

Comment: A typo solved my problem (see answer below). Thank you for your efforts guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite know why but when I accidentally typed .png twice (C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>gdal_polygonize star.png.png bla) it worked.